# How can i remove contact node

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have to remove one when contact with enemy target.I tried this,but this removes all cats.I have remove only contact cat.

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{

    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);

    if (collision == (enemyCategory | catsCategory)) {
        [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"cats" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
            [node removeFromParent];
        }];
        NSLog(@"test 1");
    }
```

Comment: *You got so much cats.*? What do you mean by that?

Comment: cats node spawning every 1 sec.When I try to remove one,All them removes.I have to remove only contacted with enemy target cat

Comment: Please edit your post and add all the related information to it. Your question is quite ambiguous now, making it difficult to understand or help. Also remember to pay attention to spelling, punctuation, and formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code:

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"cats" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
            [node removeFromParent];
        }];
```

Will remove all nodes whose name property is @"cats". Hence it is removing all the cats on screen.

You need to check whether the contact cat is the same as the one being enumerated, and then remove it.

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"cats" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([contact.bodyA.node isEqual:node] || [contact.bodyB.node isEqual:node])
        { 
            [node removeFromParent]; 
            stop = YES;
        }
    }];
```

You can read more about the `enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:` method [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:).

Comment: If this worked, please show some love by voting up and accepting this answer :P